# emmet-vim, custom map using <plug> causing problems

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

I am trying to use  to remap the emmet-vim functions, but I have some problems :
using :

```
map <c-e>e <plug>(EmmetExpandAbbr)
nmap <c-e>e <plug>(EmmetExpandAbbr)
or
map! <c-e>e <plug>(EmmetExpandAbbr)
```

nothing appens in any mode,
and using :

```
imap <c-e>e <plug>(EmmetExpandAbbr)
```

then comes a weird problem :
first, doing the sequence e in editmode,

```
div_
```

( '_' = cursor position)
becomes :

```
div<Plug>(EmmetExpandAbbr)_
```

And moreover, strange thing, the original map `<c-y>,` give the same result...

I heard that the map using  is a better way to permit the user to custom the shortcuts rather than using global variables... So how to do this with the emmet plug-in (I already succeed to custom shortcuts with other plugins)?
Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure about the parentheses?

Comment: when I do `:verbose map <c-y>,` (without the mapping modified), I see the parentheses while when I do that with another <plug> map form another plug-in, they are not displayed. I also tried without and it does not work

Comment: Anyway, if you have a problem with a plugin, use its issue tracker, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: StackOverflow is a general platform, and there is a lot of topic about vim and plugins, so I'm not sure mine is so out. Thus before signaling a bug, I prefer check if it is not what I think for now i.e. a mistake on my part

Comment: No. Always go from specific to general.